# Looping activities for a flashcard app in java

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am making a flashcard app which loops through a deck of cards. For each card, it must first show a first activity with the first word of the card and a button to flip the card. When touching the button I want another activities that shows the second word of the same card and 4 buttons to attribute a score. Then it starts over with the next card.

I have created 3 activities :

- RevisionActivity : Generates the deck of cards and loops through it (it is not visible)
- QuestionActivity : Shows the first word of the card (question) and has a button to flip the card
- AnswerActivity : Shows the second word (answer) and has 4 buttons to give a score

The problem I have is that activities don't show in the right order, so **is there a better way to do this ?**

Comment: Showing the second word (and other elements like buttons) could be simply a matter of making the views `VISIBLE` when the first button is clicked thus reducing the number of activities required.  The Q and A activities would become one QA activity.  To solve your problem of "don't show in the right order" one would have to see your transition code.

Comment: You're right, that seems to be a good idea, it might be simpler !